# merge two steps shipping method and payment information in onepage checkout in magento

Tags: magento

i m working on a projec and my client want to merge two steps shipping method and payment information  in single step, when client click on continue then shipping method and payment information both should get saved and review page should get open

Comment: can some one help me on this?

Comment: This is a very complicated thing to do. Maybe noone answers because this would be more of a pay-for-solution. Better stick to one-step-checkout extensions, if it is ok that all steps are on one page.

Comment: To SebiF i know its very complecated thing and i m trying for that for last one week but still i m not getting solution ,  i think that someone may have same problem and have the solution for it thats why i posted it here. if gets free pls try to solve this topic thanks in advance

Answer (score -2):

after working about 25 to 30 days , i have done it,i combined both the steps and is getting save from one single button ,working same as it was working earlier but still i want to do one more thing to it, i want to hide the "li id="opc-shipping_method" class="section". "

Comment: hi i am also trying to customize shipping method in checkout page, can you please tell where is the page that contain the code of shipping method i am not able to find it.. thanks

Comment: Hello. You got the solution, good. Can you tell the answer here to merge shipping and billing at one step?

Comment: Any one have got the solution ?

Comment: Please provide solution.